# How can I programmatically update the 'index unused headers' option in the Indexer Preference page under C/C++ in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

is there any possibility to change the indexer preference page - programmatically?
I want to update the index unused headers option in the indexer preference page under C/C++ - Programmatically in Eclipse RCP. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!
[Indexer Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywfxX.png)

I don't have an idea. Please guide me

Comment: I have a solution:         
**Properties properties = IndexerPreferences.getProperties(null, IndexerPreferences.SCOPE_INSTANCE);
properties.put(IndexerPreferences.KEY_INDEX_UNUSED_HEADERS_WITH_DEFAULT_LANG, String.valueOf(false));
IndexerPreferences.setProperties(null, IndexerPreferences.SCOPE_INSTANCE, properties);**

Better solutions are appreciated